# How to retrive data based on Strike prices in this case

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure and data present under it

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nifty_banknifty` (
  `instrument` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `strike_pr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_typ` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settle_pr` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contracts` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_int` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_oi` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` date DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `nifty_banknifty` (`instrument`, `symbol`, `expiry_date`, `strike_pr`, `option_typ`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `settle_pr`, `contracts`, `open_int`, `change_oi`, `date_time`) VALUES
('OPTIDX', 'NIFTY', '31-Mar-2016', '6000', 'CE', 1060.55, 1226.50, 1053.25, 1212.75, 1212.75, '684', '601650', '-1650', '2016-03-01'),
('OPTIDX', 'NIFTY', '31-Mar-2016', '7000', 'CE', 156.65, 298.90, 156.65, 289.70, 289.70, '50178', '2553975', '-163125', '2016-03-01'),
('OPTIDX', 'NIFTY', '31-Mar-2016', '6000', 'PE', 3.35, 5.20, 2.30, 2.70, 2.70, '11216', '1196350', '-2700', '2016-03-01'),
('OPTIDX', 'NIFTY', '31-Mar-2016', '7000', 'PE', 124.10, 131.75, 62.10, 66.85, 66.85, '269140', '6069025', '1134400', '2016-03-01');
```

Right now there are two strike prices 6000 and 7000 and  corresponding CE and PE open_int values respectively for each strike price

(**The Stike prices are not known in prior (that is 6000,7000 are not known earlier)**)

Could you please tell me how can i write a query to retrive each Stikre Price and CE and PE open_int  values respectively for each strike price

For example the output must be

```
Strike_Price     CE               PE

6000           601650             1196350
7000            2553975            6069025
```

This is my sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5db5b2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your response by using`CASE WHEN... END`

```
SELECT strike_pr ,
MAX(CASE WHEN option_typ = 'CE' THEN open_int END) AS CE , 
MAX(CASE WHEN option_typ = 'PE' THEN open_int END) AS PE 
FROM nifty_banknifty GROUP BY strike_pr;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5db5b2)